# Why sql order by very slow?

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

View v_one

Query 1 : `SELECT id FROM v_one LIMIT 2` : 52 ms

Query 2 : `SELECT id FROM v_one ORDER BY id LIMIT 2` : 2413 ms

View v_two

Query 3 : `SELECT id FROM v_two LIMIT 2` : 260 ms

Query 4 : `SELECT id FROM v_two ORDER BY id LIMIT 2` : 260 ms

Why on the view v_one, when using order by, the time difference so far?

Any help much appreciated

Cheers

Comment: Because it has to sort all the data.  You can speed your queries up using an index, which the second probably has.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff,  It's not sort all the data. I using limit 2. That means only 2 data

Comment: It doesn't matter because the executor has to scan all the data anyway to sort it

Comment: First it needs to sort all the data and the return the first 2 in the specified order. `LIMIT 2` tells Postgres to return up to 2 results, not to only process up to 2 records.

Comment: I using View. View different from the table. View is queries taken from multiple tables. So in view, it could not using an index

Comment: @GordonLinoff, I using view. It could not using an index

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Beside the Index as GordonLinoff say, table size can affect the time need to order the data. So be carefull when you compare queryes.

- Query1 doesnt have `ORDER BY` so just take first two elements
- Query2 is slow because `ORDER BY` need time, specially if the table is bigger and not index for `id`.
- Query3 and Query4 even when different has same time probably because this view has index or the table is small.

Last you can use EXPLAIN ANALYZE to compare query plan between both querys

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE
SELECT id FROM v_one LIMIT 2
```

Comment: I using View. View different from the table. View is queries taken from multiple tables. So in view, it could not using an index

Comment: Yes, view still use index

Comment: did you run explain analyze?

Comment: post 4 analyze in your question and I will comment on that

Comment: Solved. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

The query engine first sorts the data so it takes longer if there is no index.  The limit restricts the results after sorting data.

Hope this helps.